# How to clear Kendo Datepicker on backspace?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-datepicker

Our requirement is to be able to select a date in a Kendo Calendar and be able to clear the data on pressing backspace. I believe there is an **onkeydown** event handler where you can check *which* key has been pressed. However, we don't want to create a handler for each of our date pickers.

Is there any attribute in Kendo Datepicker that can solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It's not recomended to override backspace behaviour because if you do that if one for example want's to delete just a charachter from input will delete whole value.

You can instead select the value so one backspace will delete it and you can also unselect and delete only one char.

Please check: http://dojo.telerik.com/aCuwo

Comment: As I have said, our requirement for all date pickers is only to be able to clear the field on 1 single backspace. User is not allowed to remove 1 character at a time.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a way to  solve it via config attribute, as you properly comment, the way to do it is adding an event handler to each one of them, in the input of each date picker you could add a class:

```
<input id="datepricker1" class="deleteBack">
<input id="datepricker3" class="deleteBack">
```

Then for define their events in this way(after their initialization):

```
$(".deleteBack").on("keydown",function(e){
    if(e.which===8){
        $(this).data("kendoDatePicker").value("");
        //$(this).data("kendoDatePicker").trigger("change");//use this just if you need to trigger the change
    }
})
```